# Android takes xml only from portrait layout folder

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have created two XML files for portrait and landscape mode separately and kept them in folders **layout** and **layout-land** respectively.

**Note:** I have given **android:launchMode = "singleTask"** in manifest file for that activity for some reason.

**Issue:** In both portrait and landscape mode, it takes xml from **layout folder**. 
What is the reason for taking xml only from portrait layout folder? Is it because of the "single task property"?. What am I missing in this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try removing `android:launchMode = "singleTask`?

Comment: Do you by any chance have `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`? Also, what happens when you start the app holding the phone initially in landscape?

Comment: where did You test it? On real device/emulator or in Eclipse? If You checked it on Eclipse, You have to change the preview to landscape/portrait...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs - Yes I tested that in both device and emulator in Eclipse.

Comment: @Aleks G - yes i have android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" in manifest file.
when I start application on landscape mode it takes the layout from layout-land for both the modes portrait and landscape.But i want when it's in portrait it will take layout from layout and when landscape it will take from layout-lant

Comment: @Lalit - I cannot remove android:launchMode = "singleTask" because I need that in my activity.

Actually in my activity class there I used progress bar, when I click on button the progress bar starts and suddenly if I change the mode from portrait to landscape or landscape to portrait the progress bar stops for that I gave android:launchMode = "singleTask" in manifest. If won't use single task window leek exception occurs because of progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when you change orientation, configuration change event is fired, your activity is destroyed and recreated in the new layout.  When it's recreated, the corresponding, portrait or landscape, layout is used.

Because you indicate that you explicitly handle orientation changes, the activity is not destroyed/recreated on orientation change - and therefore the layout is not changed.  To achieve what you want, you need to store the original orientation when the app starts and then handle orientation changes in your code, something like this:

```
private int currentOrientation;

public void onCreate(Bundle sis) {
    ...
    currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
}

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if(currentOrientation != newConfig.orientation) {
        //re-set the layout into your activity
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
        currentOrientation = newConfig.orientation;
    }
}
```

Depending on your logic, you may want to get values from existing views and re-set them after re-setting the layout.

Comment: Thanks @Aleks G for the answer. I will definitely try this and come back with the reply asap.

Comment: @Aleks..I have an issue, when my activity restarts on changing mode there is an edit text box and a progress bar(progress bar is inside edit text box) so how can i retain there states. when I change the mode text box is showing empty and progress bar starts automatically. Note : I declared android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" on manifest file.

Comment: @vivek_25 With that declaration in manifest, the activity should NOT restart.  And you will be controlling the configuration changes with the method I indicated.  You can still achieve the same restarting the activity, but then you'll need to use `Bundle` to save/restore your instance state.  Read about activity lifecycle.